# use of deleted function 'std::pair<const std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am using `std::pair<string, string>` and `make_pair()` to create a `std::map` using this pair of strings. But I am getting the following compilation error:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:140:22: error: use of deleted function 'std::pair<const std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >, firmware_data>::~pair()'
  destroy(_Up* __p) { __p->~_Up(); }
```

The declarations I have done is as follows:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, string> FirmwareKey_t;
typedef std::map<FirmwareKey_t, firmware_data_t> FirmwareDataMap_t;
```

Where `firmware_data_t` is a struct object, defined as:

```
typedef struct firmware_data {
  string name;
  value_t abc; // value_t is of union type
  bool configurable;
  update_status_t def; //update_status_t is of enum type

} firmware_data_t;
```

Union Declaration:

```
typedef union value {
  string string_val;
  bool boolean_val;
  int64_t int_val;
  uint uint_val;
} value_t;
```

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, make sure you read the description of every tag you apply to your question!

Comment: Hi @UlrichEckhardt, I tried my best to provide the required info, please let me know if you want more info on this. And sure for next time will read the description  before tagging.

Comment: You need to at least include the type definitions involved.

Comment: Also, the `typedef struct` thing is a C-ism that is just clutter in C++.

Comment: You can still [edit] your question to fix all this.

Answer (score 3):

The error is saying that the `map`'s `value_type` (aka `std::pair<const Key, T>`) has a deleted destructor.

For that to happen, either the `map::key_type` or `map::mapped_type` type (in this case, `FirmwareKey_t` and `firmware_data_t`, respectively) has a deleted destructor. That is clearly not the case for `FirmwareKey_t`, so it must be `firmware_data_t`, which contains a `value_t` member of `union` type. [According to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union):

> (since C++11) If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment, **or destructor**), **that function is deleted by default in the union** and needs to be defined explicitly by the programmer.

Which means one of the fields in your `union` is of a non-trivial type that has a destructor defined, and so the `union` itself has a deleted destructor, and thus any type that uses the `union` as a data member also has a deleted destructor, and so on.

And, in fact, that field in your `union` is the `string string_val` field.

So, you need to fix your `union`. Since `std::string` requires destruction, you need to explicitly define a destructor for your `union` to call `std::string`'s destructor, but only when `string_val` is the active field of the `union`, eg:

```cpp
union value_t {
  string string_val;
  bool boolean_val;
  int64_t int_val;
  uint uint_val;

  ~value_t() {
    if (some condition indicating string_val is active) {
      string_val.~string();
    }
  }
};.
```

You will also need to define a copy costructor and copy assignment operator for your `union`, too.

That being said, a better solution is to use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead of a `union`. `std::variant` is a type-safe `union` that handles these details automatically for you.

```
using value_t = variant<string, bool, int64_t, uint>;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy for your quick and descriptive answer. Hope i will able to resolve this with this info. Just to let you know, i included union declaration above.

Comment: After updating the code as we discussed above, the errors got resolved but now seeing following errors:1) required from here /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:140:49: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >; _T2 = firmware_data]'
    _M_value_field(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...) { } 2)/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h:127:17: error: use of deleted function 'firmware_data::firmware_data(const firmware_data&)'. Do we need to add constructor also?

Comment: @snehadaf yes, per the cppreference quote in my answer. You are seeing the result of your union's copy constructor being deleted because `std::string` has a copy constructor. Another reason to use `std::variant` instead.

Comment: Ok, i am trying to understand usage of variant and how to implement it with minimal code changes in my implementation. But if in case i need to continue with union only, then do you have any example or implementation? That will be great help, I will go though it and will try to fix this in current implementation only.

Comment: @snehadaf `std:; variant` is way better than unions, you should use it if you can.

Comment: @snehadaf you are likely going to have problems implementing this with your `union` because it provides no direct way of indicating which of its fields is active at any given time. Without that, you can't invoke the `std::string`'s constructors and destructor at the correct time. So, you need to either 1) add another field, like an enum, to indicate the active field; 2) change the `std::string` to a fixed `char[]` array; or 3) switch to `std::variant`, which handles all of this internally for you.